# Is fakechroot a security flaw?

Tags: linux, chroot, chroot-jail

I recently know more about `fakechroot`.
AFAIK it seems dangerous since it escalates user privilege, even if it's in chroot. I'm aware of `fakeroot` but it is not the same since you can't do anything with it that requires root.

However with `fakechroot` you can actually execute things require root privilege inside chroot. So does that mean using `fakechroot` normal user have a possibility to rooted chroot and then break out as a root on host ?

I read on their man page that `fakechroot` doesn't escalate user privilege, which I'm not sure that I fully understand.

Answer (score 6):

Some Linux applications will only work if the current user is `root`.
Most of these applications relate to changing Linux itself, so are
protected from ordinary users.

However, sometimes, when working as an ordinary user, we would like to run
such commands without elevation to `root`, only for temporarily
using these commands for specific purpose.

Such commands are not a security flaw, because they run under the current
user and without any real effect upon the running version of Linux.

---

Best example for such commands is `fakeroot`.
Its function is to *pretend* that the current user is `root`,
without this actually happening.

This allows programs which expect to be run as root to actually run as a
normal user, while wrongly thinking that the root-requiring operations
succeed.

This is used typically when building a package, so that the installation process of the package being installed can proceed without error, even if it runs `chown root:root`, or `install -o root`, etc.
`fakeroot` remembers the fake ownership which it pretended to give these files,
so subsequent operations examining the ownership will see `root` as the owner
instead of the real one.

This allows, for example, subsequent `tar` runs to store files as owned by
root. `fakeroot` will in this case create a tarball containing files owned
by root and suid.
However, you won’t be able to extract that tarball and preserve those permissions unless you do so as root, with no privilege escalation.

`fakeroot` then allows to run a build as a regular user,
while preserving the effects the build would have had if it had been
run as root, allowing them to be replayed later.
Applying the effects "for real" will require real root privileges,
for which `fakeroot` doesn’t provide any method of acquiring.

---

Another example is [fakechroot](https://linux.die.net/man/1/fakechroot).
`fakechroot` is a regular non-setuid program. It does not enhance a user's privileges, or decrease the system's security.
It creates an environment where it's possible to use the chroot(8) command
without root privileges, useful for calling `apt` to install packages
without need for root privileges.
The user this way creates a root environment within his own little bubble
without affecting anyone else on the system.

`fakechroot` does not provide the `fakeroot` functionality,
so requires calling `fakechroot` via the `fakeroot` command.
These two commands are complementary and are many times used together.

Comment: Yep, the Unsung was awarded on `Jan 10 '16 at 21:51` which was like 3 months into my membership on SU afaik. The fanatic is just visiting everyday I suppose. They should have an "Addicted to Answering" badge, or "The Bounty Hunter" badge because it's not new news that HarryMC lives up to that sh%&! Did you get rich off GME too by chance? How about BTC, you tucked a few hundred BC away for a rainy day, right? Lol. Hit me up Prince HarryMC!

Comment: @harrymc: Hi, thank you for your answer. But I'm not sure it answered my question, when you run those commands with `fakeroot`, it just records that we're running as root, without actually using it for anything, you cannot access resources that requires root privilege, you cannot run `apt` with `fakeroot`. Such thing is possible with `fakechroot`, meaning `fakechroot` actually gives access to those resources, hence security flaw ?

Comment: No security flaw - your software just *thinks* that it has access to the system root, but it's actually just a fake, and all updates happen only in your folder in your own little bubble which is isolated from the real system.